# Complex jQuery dependency in Nodejs module

Tags: jquery, node.js, dependencies

My nodejs module requires jQuery version that includes Sizzle having this commit: https://github.com/jquery/sizzle/commit/ccb809ff416b06ca86abe54ce273c40f2271d3b5

For now, this commit only exists in newest jQuery 1.x (1.11.1) and newest 2.x (2.1.1).
So, minimal supported jQuery version is 1.11.1, but jQuery 2.0 isn't suitable for me, though 2.0 > 1.11.1

So, I need some weird kind of dependency: *1.11.1+ if jQuery 1.x, and 2.1.1+ if jQuery 2.x*

Something like *">= 1.11.1 < 2.0 | >= 2.1.1"*

How I can write such kind of dependency in package.json?

Answer (score 0):

You can find some examples similar to your situation if you scroll down on the [npm website package.json explanation](https://www.npmjs.org/doc/files/package.json.html). The values must be parse-able by the [node-semver](https://www.npmjs.org/doc/misc/semver.html) module, which comes with npm.  You could do:

```
"dependencies": {
  "jQuery": "^1.11.1 || >=2.1.1",
```

[The ^ above is a shorthand for >=1.11.1 < 2.0.0](http://browsenpm.org/package.json#devDependency.vows) if this condition is not satisfied, then the `||` operator takes effect and the second condition supplied `">=2.1.1"` is checked.